# Extra Column in DatagridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

How to remove the extra column in the Left with * in DataGridView?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`RowHeadersVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle.rowheadersvisible(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

*(I know its name is quite misleading but it works :))*

For the following code:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Address");
dt.Rows.Add("ABC", "DEF");
dt.Rows.Add("XYZ", "DEF");
dt.Rows.Add("EFG", "HIJ");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

You will get like:

[image]

Without that property set to false, it will appear as:

[image]